# Automating mouse click with Powershell whenever sound output stops?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

Is it possible to write a script which detects system volume level and initiate an automatic mouse click whenever all sounds stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Set-PC-Volume-1737b160) to get the volume state.

After that you can trigger a `WShell.SendKeys` method to send the keys like this:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$windows=Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle
$WindowTitle=($windows | ? {$_ -match "YourAppWindow"} ).MainWindowTitle
$wshell.AppActivate($WindowTitle)
$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
```